# Is there any reason to still use int as opposed to long on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: java, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

In general, is there any reason to still use `int` as opposed to `long` in Java if programming on a 64 bit architecture?

**Specifically in my case:**

I use `int` variables that are being mapped to keys(sequential numbers starting from 1 and incremented for each new entry) of type [NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm#CJACDECG) on an Oracle DB table.

The DB type `NUMBER` has way more precision then `int` so the correct way to model this on the Java side would be `long`.

I stuck to `int` for efficiency reasons and because probably we will never have so many entries in the table as to need more than an `int` can represent.

On the other hand, since most modern machines are 64 bit anyways, it shouldn't make a difference regarding efficiency on the Java side to use `long` as opposed to `int`, right? I guess it would make a difference memory wise if you load huge lists of keys into memory but we are not doing this kind of operation.

Comment: I don't want to waste memory if it can fit in `int`

Comment: @UmaKanth while valid, you could run into the [Gangnam-Style problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2nsnvr/gangnam_styles_video_has_passed_the_maximum/). If memory is not an issue and you cannot guarantee, that overflows are prevented, use `long`. Altough I am not sure whether `long`s are optimized for 64-bit JVMs (adhoc, I cannot find any references confirming/rebutting the support).

Comment: How sure can you be that you won't **ever** have to go back to a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @KevinWorkman It is a trade-off. If you go back to a 32-bit machine, your code runs slower with `long`. If you use `int`, your code runs "unsafer" (of course, `long`s can overflow as well, but this takes much longer).

Comment: long and int operations on a 64 bit CPU should perform similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 64-bit processor, `long` will give a marginal performance boost because of alignment, registers, whatever (whether or not this is actually palpable is debatable). This comes with a drawback of using more space on the stack and heap, which could itself impact performance negatively. Really, it depends on your program, since there are so many factors that could impact performance.

I would recommend to use `int`, unless you specifically need a 64-bit number. If you know for sure you're programming for an x86_64 architecture, then I think it wouldn't really matter, since these are optimized to handle 32-bit programs very efficiently anyways.